# Why doesn't the image change based on the viewport in HTML?

Tags: html, google-chrome, atom-editor

I'm learning web development and as always start by html5. I've been stuck in the viewport because I set up 3 images for each type of viewport and only see the one I have configured by default. When changing the viewport in Chrome browser the image doesn't change.

I tried running an html5 file with Firefox and nothing happens. I ran it on a localhost with prepros and nothing happens.

```
<img
     src="img/image.jpg"
     srcset "img/image2.jpg 1.5x,
             img/image3.jpg 2x"
>
```

Comment: You forgot your `=` for `srcset`. Since this is s simple typo I would recommend deleting this question.

Comment: I just fixed the error update the localhost and still do not change the images when changing the scale of the viewport